# Crashlytics Framework not recognizing

Tags: ios, crashlytics

When i imported the framework into my delegate file it is not recognising it giving ".h file not found" error. I followed the same procedure before for my another application and it is working fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something is wrong with the header paths in your project settings.

Comment: If you upgraded to Xcode 5.1, you have to get grid of the arm64 platform target for now. Simply follow these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22370158/481621

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure the `Crashlytics.framework` is added to the solution. Follow the instructions of the "Crashlytics" application...

Normally the "Crashlytics.framework" directory is added to directory containing your `*.xcodeproj` project file. Try adding `$(SRCROOT)` to the `Framework Search Path`.

Comment: Try adding $(SRCROOT) to the Framework Search Path. - Worked. I have changed the location of .framework to other folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you're experiencing this issue on a build server (e.g. Team City) make sure that you've selected `Automatically on agent (if supported by VCS roots)` for your `VCS Checkout mode` in your `Version Control Settings`.

Comment: I have the same problem but on Jenkins... Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I have reinstalled the framework, which only takes 2-3 minutes and . The problem might be caused by that you have relocated the Crashlytics.framework to another subfolder from the root directory or 64 bit transition as Martin stated.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048098/936957 for details.