# Project crashes claiming to not know where Crashlytics is, so I add $(SRCROOT) to my framework search paths, but that causing a linker error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, crashlytics

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754233/crashlytics-file-not-found) when my project was complaining about not being able to find Crashlytics. It worked fine, and now the project actually compiles, but it now states:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/pathtoproject...'

What exactly am I doing wrong? All I have in Framework Search Paths is `$(inherited)`, `$(SRCROOT)` and the path to the project.

All I could think of was that I duplicated the project in order to test solutions and now the project folder is called "*formerprojectname* copy" but I tried adding copy to the project path in Framework Search Paths but it then couldn't find Crashlytics again.

How do I solve this issue? It's rather annoying.

Comment: Did you make $(SRCROOT) recursive? It should work if you do, (assuming you're framework is somewhere in there).

Comment: @JasperBlues Just made it recursive and nothing changed.

Comment: I'm not sure what else it might be. . . can you attach a screenshot of your linker flags?