# Crashlytics.h not found Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode8, crashlytics

I am trying to build an old project in Xcode 8.0 and getting the error at:

```
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

Error is:

> 'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found

I am very new in iOS Apps development. Just installed Xcode 8.0 and opened the old project.

Any suggestions pleaese?

Comment: u checked ur file is in ur directory or not ... check the path once .....

Comment: Have you added framework as well in embedded binaries?

Comment: I think u need to update the pod files in ur project ....  goto ur project directory from ur keychain and update the pad.

Comment: Files are there in the project directory with name, Crashlytics.framework.

Comment: how to added crashlytics framework in project ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashlytics file not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754233/crashlytics-file-not-found)

Comment: @KKRocks I didn't add it. I just opened the project in Xcode, compiled and came up with this error.

Comment: then you need to add crashlytic frameworks again through https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following these instructions to re-install crashlytics correctly into your project. Most of the time these errors occur if the it wasn't installed/configured correctly:

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

**EDIT**
If you are not using cocoapods you can install manually following these instructions:

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I first remove the framework from the Xcode Linked Frameworks and Libraries and delete from the project folder too?

Comment: For best results it would be a good idea to delete the old and re-install, just to make sure you don't get any clashes. Don't forget to upvote my answer and mark it as answered if this helps :)